# Show transparent BLOB .png

Tags: php, image, blob

Ok, so I changed my code after a little googling and reading comments.

But now get this error

> Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in
>   /home/realcas/public_html/eshop/ecms/system/classes/photofetch.php on
>   line 51 ‰PNG  IHDRâI¯©m­ Warning: imagepng() [function.imagepng]:
>   gd-png: fatal libpng error: zlib error in
>   /home/realcas/public_html/eshop/ecms/system/classes/photofetch.php on
>   line 54
>
> Warning: imagepng() [function.imagepng]: gd-png error: setjmp returns
>   error condition in
>   /home/realcas/public_html/eshop/ecms/system/classes/photofetch.php on
>   line 54
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/realcas/public_html/eshop/ecms/system/classes/photofetch.php:51)
>   in /home/realcas/public_html/eshop/ecms/system/classes/photofetch.php
>   on line 55

Here is the new code

```
<?
include_once('database.php');



//Fetch basic Profile
class fetchphoto extends Database{


        public function countrysize($id){
        $this->id = $id;
            $array=preg_split('#(?<!\\\)\:#',$this->id); 

            if($array[1] == "9177156176671")
            {
            $max_width = 226;

            $max_height = 3000;
            }
             $sth = mysql_query("SELECT categoryimage FROM shop_categories WHERE id = '".$array[0]."'");

                while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
                $blobcontents = $r["categoryimage"];

                $im = imagecreatefromstring($blobcontents);

                $x = imagesx($im);
                $y = imagesy($im);

                $ratioh = $max_height/$y;
                $ratiow = $max_width/$x;
                $ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow);
                // New dimensions
                $width = intval($ratio*$x);
                $height = intval($ratio*$y);







                 // Temporarily increase the memory limit to allow for larger images
                ini_set('memory_limit', '32M'); 


            // create a new blank image
            $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

            // Copy the old image to the new image
            imagecopyresampled($newImage, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $w, $y);

            // Output to a temp file
            imagepng($newImage, null, 10);  
            header('Content-type: image/png');
            return $newImage;

            // Free memory                           
            imagedestroy($newImage);
            }


    }



}

$fetchpicture = new fetchphoto();
$fetchpicture->Connect();
$fetchpicture->DB();
$fetchpicture->countrysize($_GET['pic']);
$fetchpicture->CloseDB();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not really clear on what the problems are that you are experiencing. Providing more detail on the problem will help.

That being said, is the problem your Content-Type header? In your code snippet you are passing `Content-Type: <span class="posthilit">image</span>/png` when it should be `Content-Type: image/png`.

Also, it looks like you are destroying the image before you send it out to the client - try moving `imagedestory($im)` after you call `imagepng($im, null, 300)`.

Be sure to check your return values too! `imagecopyresampled` can return `true` on success and `false` on failure which can help you narrow down the part that fails.

**EDIT**: As Korvin Szanto said, you'll also want to set [imagealphablending](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagealphablending.php) to true.

### Response to update

A couple things noticed in your new code:

1. You create the variable `$im` from `imagecreatefromstring` but later you use `$img` when calling `imagecopyresampled`.
2. When calling `imagecopyresampled` you're using the variable `$w` when it should be `$x`.
3. Please, please, *please* start checking your return values instead of blindly accepting that they work. You may have been able to catch the problem at `imagecopyresampled` if you were checking them in the first place.
4. You need to output your header *before* you output the image itself - otherwise you'll get a "headers already sent" error.
5. You need to move `imagedestroy` *before* the return. Once your function returns, nothing after it will execute - so your image will never be destroyed. Also, you will need to destroy the original PNG too - so add in a `imagedestroy($im)` before your return statement.

Comment: He's also going to want to set [`imagealphablending`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagealphablending.php) to true with `imagealphblending($im,true);`

Comment: Sorry It did not even load the image once I made those changes

Comment: seriously, check your variables before you post code to a website.